# windows jadejs watch not working properly

Tags: windows, pug, watch

platform: win7
node-version: v0.10.4
jade-version: 0.29.0

I want to use jade options to watch the slider direcotry in:

`d:/webwork/`

my command is:

`jade -w -P ./slider`

and get the cmd result below:

```
jade -w -P ./slider
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\node_modules\monocle\monocle.js:125
        watched_directories[directory] = (new Date(stats.mtime)).getTime();
                                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mtime' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade\node_modules\monocle\monocle.js:125:57
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

If I want to use the jade default option -w to watch the file changes, what command should I use?